# Copy images in Google Drive to own server using PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have a folder in Google Drive with product images (the folder is public). On request I want these images to be uploaded to my website.

Is there a simple way to copy all images to my own server using PHP, whitout having to set my mind into Google Drive API?

This gives me nothing to work with:

```
<?php    
   $url = "https-link-to-the-public-folder";    
   $html= file_get_contents($url);    
   print_r($html);    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward method for uploading a file is by making a simple upload request. This option is a good choice when:

- The file is small enough to upload again in its entirety if the connection fails.
- There is no metadata to send. This might be true if you plan to send metadata for this resource in a separate request, or if no metadata is supported or available.

To use simple upload, make a POST or PUT request to the method's /upload URI and add the query parameter **uploadType=media**. For example:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media
```

The HTTP headers to use when making a simple upload request include:

- Content-Type. Set to one of the method's accepted upload media data types, specified in the API reference.
- Content-Length. Set to the number of bytes you are uploading. Not required if you are using chunked transfer encoding.

The following example shows the use of a simple upload request for the Drive API.

```
POST /upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: number_of_bytes_in_file
Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token

JPEG data
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though I am not interested in UPloading files to Google Drive. I am interested in DOWNloading files from Google Drive to my server. All images in a Google Drive folder. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Gordova, Please let us know, whether you got the solution or not.